# MPI FFTW, multiple fftw_mpi_local_size calls

Tags: mpi, fftw

I need to forward/backward transform the 3-components vector field `v`, and the scalar field `p`. Both `v` and `p` are 3D arrays and have the same domain size.

According to the FFTW documentation, I should for example call `fftwf_mpi_local_size_many_transposed` twice: one for `v`, with `howmany=3`, and one for `p` with `howmany=1`.

Could the two function calls could return two different domain decompositions?

I tried to answer this question myself, but I got lost inside [local_size_guru](https://github.com/FFTW/fftw3/blob/master/mpi/api.c#L248).
In case they are possibly returning two different decompositions, how can I enforce a single consistent decomposition for both `v` and `p`, without having 3 separate transforms on `v`?